# Un Informe con dos consultas

Tags: pentaho, reporting

Estoy usando pentaho report y necesito usar varias consultas exactamente iguales pero con distintos valores. (Los campos son iguales  sus valores no) He intentado usar un subInforme al que le asigno la segunda consulta, pero el resultado es que por cada fila del informe maestro me hace todas las filas del subInforme.

El subInforme lo meto en el details del informe principal.

Los campos del subInforme también los pongo en el detail del subInforme.

Lo que necesito es un informe que sea algo así

```
Consulta1            Consulta2

2017                  2020
2034                  3323
```

He probado a hacer una formula con este valor `=MULTIVALUEQUERY("miquery"`) pero solo me toma el primer valor de la query y me lo repite tantas veces como la query principal

Comment: Hola Lorenzo, trata de agregar en tus preguntas un poco de tus consultas, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad puedes usar `MULTIVALUEQUERY` , la diferencia con `SINGLEVALUEQUERY`  es que en lugar de retornar un solo valor, retorna todos los  valores del  listado, (incluso puedes definir un limite de elementos).

```
MULTIVALUEQUERY([Query]; [columna]; [query timeout]; [limite] )
```

Por lo tanto con ambos solo obtendrás los valores de una columna.

si tu problema es :

> he probado a hacer una formula con este valor =MULTIVALUEQUERY("miquery") pero solo me toma el primer valor de la query y me lo repite tantas veces como la query principal

Solo debería entregarte un valor usando `MULTIVALUEQUERY()` por lo tanto deberías revisar la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

AL final lo he solucionado con un `SINGLEVALUEQUERY("nombreConsulta")`,  Esto me seleciona solo un campo de hay su nombre. Lo que tenia mal era la consulta, en la consulta le he puesto en la clausula Where de la primera consulta que el campo name sea igual que el campo name de la segunda consulta. 
SL final se trataba de enlazar las dos consultas por el nombre que es el campo identificativo en mis consultas.